# How to read subfolders in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write a pipeline jenkins job that loop through the subfolder of a specific directory and launch something. The problem is to access the filesystem. For some reason it does not seems to read the file system at all, neither its own workspace.

This is the snippet I'm using

```
node ('label') {
    workspacePath = '/opt/installersWS'
    ws(workspacePath){
        stage ("test"){
            ...some stuff...
            runtimeBuildDir = new File(workspacePath + "/components")
            echo runtimeBuildDir.getPath()
            if (runtimeBuildDir.exists()){
                echo "search for subfolders"
            } else {
                echo "main folder not existing"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The folder of course is existing on the server but the run always return with the second echo.

**UPDATE:**
I discover that all the gradle/java instruction given in this way is not targeting the node but are running on the master. This was why I didn't found the directories. So I was completely misunderstanding how the pipeline is working.

Said that.. any idea on how can I retrieve that? Is there a way to set an gradle property from the shell step for example?

Thanks,
Michele

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below solved my issue. It could help someone who is looking for the same. 
Sub folders can be added to list using function which returns the list of directory in pipeline like below.

```
@NonCPS
def readDir()
{
    def  dirsl = [] 
    new File("${workspace}").eachDir()
    {
        dirs -> println dirs.getName() 
        if (!dirs.getName().startsWith('.')) {
            dirsl.add(dirs.getName())
        }
    }
    dirsl
}
```

Then in your pipeline script, call the function like below and do whatever is required.

```
stage ('Build'){

    dirsl = readDir()
    def size = dirsl.size()
    print size
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        "Do whatever appropriate"
    }
}
```

Comment: `new File("${workspace}")` is a bit redundant: its simpler to write `new File(workspace)`

Comment: This will only work in case you're running it on the Jenkins master (as build agent) - or am I missing something?

Comment: Verified that this fails on non-master nodes

Comment: Can someone please explain why this doesn't work on non-master nodes? In the mean time I am using this solution instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/60180867

Answer (score 6):

This is the way I solved it, running a shell that returned the output

```
def subfolders = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'ls -d RuntimeBuild/*').trim().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
```

Then I was able to cicle the list with the name of the directories and manipulate them.

For Windows that could become:

```
def subfolders = bat(script: '@dir /B RuntimeBuild', returnStdout: true).split(/\n\r/)
```

Comment: Please note that `System.getProperty("line.separator")` will not work when running the Jenkins master on a different OS than the build agent as it will return the line separator for the OS running on the Jenkins master. In addition I suppose it will not be possible to use it when running in the sandbox. But replacing it by `\n` should do the trick on a linux build agent.

Comment: That @ in front of dir seem important to make it work. Can you tell me why?