# How to list all directories from within directory in jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to get all directories present in particular directory from jenkins pipeline script.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 25):

If you want a list of all directories under a specific directory e.g. `mydir` using Jenkins Utility plugin you can do this:

Assuming `mydir` is under the current directory:

```java
 dir('mydir') {
   def files = findFiles() 
 
   files.each{ f -> 
      if(f.directory) {
        echo "This is directory: ${f.name} "
      }
   }
 }
```

Just make sure you do **NOT** provide `glob` option. Providing that makes `findFiles` to return file names only.

More info: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/

Comment: "Just make sure you do NOT provide glob option. Providing that makes findFiles to return file names only."  thank you thank you thank you!  I 'love' how clearly the docs mention that strange behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find any plugin to list folders, so I used sh/bat script in pipeline, and also this will work irrespective of operating system.

```java
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Find all fodlers from given folder') {
      steps {
        script {
                    
          def foldersList = []
                    
          def osName = isUnix() ? "UNIX" : "WINDOWS"
          echo "osName: " + osName
    
          echo ".... JENKINS_HOME: ${JENKINS_HOME}"
    
          if(isUnix()) {
            def output = sh returnStdout: true, script: "ls -l ${JENKINS_HOME} | grep ^d | awk '{print \$9}'"
            foldersList = output.tokenize('\n').collect() { it }
          } else {
            def output = bat returnStdout: true, script: "dir \"${JENKINS_HOME}\" /b /A:D"
            foldersList = output.tokenize('\n').collect() { it }
            foldersList = foldersList.drop(2)
                     
          }
          echo ".... " + foldersList
        }            
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but I would look at the findFiles step provided by the [Jenkins Pipeline Utility Steps Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) and set glob to an ant-style directory patter, something like '**/*/'

Comment: I already tried findFiles step, but this lists only files and not directories.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to log them, use

```
sh("ls -A1 ${myDir}")
```

for Linux/Unix.  (Note: that's a capital letter A and the number one.)

Or, use

```
bat("dir /B ${myDir}")
```

for Windows.

If you want the list of files in a variable, you'll have to use

```
def dirOutput = sh("ls -A1 ${myDir}", returnStdout: true)
```

or

```
def dirOutput = bat("dir /B ${myDir}", returnStdout: true)
```

and then parse the output.

Comment: Thanks for this! This helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recursively getting all the Directores within a directory.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      steps {
        script {
            def directories = getDirectories("$WORKSPACE")
            echo "$directories"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@NonCPS
def getDirectories(path) {
    def dir = new File(path)
    def dirs = []
    dir.traverse(type: groovy.io.FileType.DIRECTORIES, maxDepth: -1) { d ->
        dirs.add(d) 
    }
    return dirs
}
```

Comment: Seems this only works when run on master node.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for the very end of Jenkinsfile:

```sh
post {
    always {
        echo '\n\n-----\nThis build process has ended.\n\nWorkspace Files:\n'
        sh 'find ${WORKSPACE} -type d -print'
    }
}
```

Place the `find` wherever you think is better. Check more alternatives at [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32678/how-can-i-list-subdirectories-recursively)

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But this will work only on unix/linux system. I want an operating system independent solution.

Comment: Understood. Consider then an edit to your question, since this restriction is not there.

Answer (score 0):

```
def findSubFolder(String base_folder) {
    dir(base_folder) {
        findFiles().findAll { item -> item.directory }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?