# List files from a git folder as parameter list in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a folder "processes" in my project, I want to display the subfolders as an input parameter list. I have written code like so -

```
parameters([
    [
        $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
        description: '', 
        filterLength: 1, 
        filterable: false, 
        name: 'TreeTypes',  
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: ''
            ], 
            script: [
                classpath: [], 
                sandbox: false, 
                script: 'files = findFiles(glob: "processes") return files'
            ]
        ]
    ] 
])

pipeline {
//rest of the stages
}
```

This does not populate the folders inside processes.
The following is my project structure. Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong?

```
Project-Root 
|->fileA
|->processes
|     |->dir1->some_file.txt
|     |->dir2->another_file.txt
|->Jenkinsfile
```

Comment: try change `sandbox: false` to `sandbox: true` and `return files.split("\n")`

Comment: tried, seems not to work :(

Comment: I included a method inspired by second answer from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620409/how-to-read-subfolders-in-jenkins-pipeline
It works, when the method is called in a stage, but won't when I call it in a parameter script field.